# How can I setState() another input value with a button in the same component in React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

How can I `setState()` another input value with a button in the same component in React?
I'm using the `onClick` event handler on the button.
I want to make the `handleClick`function which I gave it to the button, to target the value of the input

```
class Search extends Component {
  state = {
    searchInput: "",
  };

  handleClick = () => {
    this.setState({
      searchInput: input.value,
    });
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <input type="text"/>
        <button onClick={this.handleClick}>Enter</button>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: It's not clear what you're asking.

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow.  Please read the posting guidelines https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and consider adjusting your question to conform to them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question is not clear, I believe you are asking how to set the value of an input field when you press a button in react.

If that is correct, then you have done most of the work already, all you need to do now is add an `<input>` tag.

Like this:

```
<input type="text" value={ this.state.searchInput } />
```

If I have misunderstood your question then please clarify.

It may be worth reading about how **State** and **Lifecycle** work in React [Here](https://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html)

Whenever the `setState()` function is triggered, React automatically runs the `render()` function in any components where state has changed, rerendering that component with the new state values.

**Edit**

After clarification I now understand exactly what you want.

You require the use of a ref, like this:

```
 class Search extends Component {
   state = {
     searchInput: "",
   };

   handleClick = () => {
     this.setState({
       searchInput: this.inputText,
     });
   };

   render() {
     return (
       <div>
         <input type="text" ref={(x) => this.inputText = x}/>
         <button onClick={this.handleClick}>Enter</button>
       </div>
     );
   }
 }
```

Comment: I want to make handleClick function which I gave it to the button, to target the value of the input.

Comment: Check out the edit that I made to the bottom of my post.

Answer (score 0):

instead of using a button to update the state try this:
`<input type="text" onChange={(e) => this.setState({searchInput: e.target.value }) />`

Comment: Yeah but I want to use the button o set the state.

Comment: in the input field instead of `this.inputText = x` try `this.inputText = x.target.value`